# Uploading to GCS

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am working on a pipeline to upload data to BQ. My first step is to upload data to GCS. I know Storage has api but it also has gsutil. Would one somehow script gsutil or would I need to reimplement everything gsutil provides? My goal is to provide java api for upload so the user would not need to install gsutil. Could anyone advise whether that is possible? Is there gsutil jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need to 'reimplement' everything gsutil provide because someone already did it :) You should use the [GCS Java client](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/) - It will give you all the ability to built on top of it a layer that gives your users the options to work with GCS without the need to install or work with command line (=gsutil).